# Meteor JS App for admin and for store front

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to load different js ang css for admin route and store front route.

I am planning to create a e-commerce site using meteor. I do not want to load admin js and css to the store front page.

any ideas?

Comment: if you want completly new interface and no dependencies with the app, you can create seperate app with same MONGO_URL, so that you can use some templates like http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0R5L90S which have meteor version available , it will save development time and no extra code to sent to client on main app, this is how I do it

Comment: PS: I'm not anyway relate or know the developers of that template, I use it my app and I liked that template, just another way to see the problem. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment Meteor doesn't let you decide what is loaded neither how it is loaded. Every HTML and CSS file is going to be sent over to the client no matter what you do.

It is however on their [roadmap to implement incremental loading](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading) so you might be able to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out reactioncommerce.com. They're working on a meteor based, open source e-commerce platform.